# How do I get my dropdown aligned with nav?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I get my navigation dropdown to align with the navigation bar which its supposed to drop under? Thanks in advance.

```css
#navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
}
#nav ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 10px 45px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: hidden;
  color: white;
}
li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #FFBE4A;
  color: black;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#OurClubTitle">Our Club</a></li>
      <li><a href="#OurTeamsTitle">Our Teams</a></li>
      <li><a href="#penaltyTitle">Score a Penalty</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#contactUsTitle" class="dropbtn">Contact Us</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#trainingTitle">Training Nights</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#extraSpecialTitle">Extra Special</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. I'm a novice to all this so please be gentle. Thanks

Comment: Just aligned to the nav bar or also below the specific nav item (in your case contact us)?

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `position: relative` to the `.dropdown` and set your `.dropdown` on hover to `left: 0`

**Changes:**

```
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; // added
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  left: 0px; // added
}
```

```css
#navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
}
#nav ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 10px 45px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: hidden;
  color: white;
}
li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #FFBE4A;
  color: black;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#OurClubTitle">Our Club</a></li>
      <li><a href="#OurTeamsTitle">Our Teams</a></li>
      <li><a href="#penaltyTitle">Score a Penalty</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#contactUsTitle" class="dropbtn">Contact Us</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#trainingTitle">Training Nights</a>
          <a href="#trainingTitle">Training Nights</a>
          <a href="#trainingTitle">Training Nights</a>
          <a href="#trainingTitle">Training Nights</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#extraSpecialTitle">Extra Special</a>     
      </li>

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#contactUsTitle" class="dropbtn">Test</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#trainingTitle">one</a>
          <a href="#trainingTitle">two</a>
          <a href="#trainingTitle">three</a>
          <a href="#trainingTitle">four</a>
        </div>
      </li>      
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

add **position: relative** to your *li.dropdown* and **left: 0;** to your *.dropdown-content*:

```
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 0;
}
```

```css
#navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
}
#nav ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 10px 45px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: hidden;
  color: white;
}
li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #FFBE4A;
  color: black;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 0;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#OurClubTitle">Our Club</a></li>
      <li><a href="#OurTeamsTitle">Our Teams</a></li>
      <li><a href="#penaltyTitle">Score a Penalty</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#contactUsTitle" class="dropbtn">Contact Us</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#trainingTitle">Training Nights</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#extraSpecialTitle">Extra Special</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The menu point "Trainign Nights" is not reachable for the normal user (or they fast moving ;-)). remove the `top: 40px`

Answer (score 1):

You need `position: relative;` on `li.dropdown` to have a reference point for the absolute position of `.dropdown-content`,  and you need to use  `left: 0;` on `.dropdown-content` to align it with its parent element `li.dropdown`:

```css
#navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
}
#nav ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 10px 45px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: hidden;
  color: white;
}
li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #FFBE4A;
  color: black;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#OurClubTitle">Our Club</a></li>
      <li><a href="#OurTeamsTitle">Our Teams</a></li>
      <li><a href="#penaltyTitle">Score a Penalty</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#contactUsTitle" class="dropbtn">Contact Us</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#trainingTitle">Training Nights</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#extraSpecialTitle">Extra Special</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want it below the specific item, just change your `#nav ul li` styling like this:

```
#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: hidden;
  color: white;
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/zKVyVW)

Just to mention. This approach will set some margins to your nav elements. That's owed to `inline-block`. If that's bothering you also add `margin: 0` to your `#nav ul li`.

Comment: @karlb123 Glad I could help. Just keep in mind that your nav will somehow 'jump' a bit, due to that margin. I've edited my answer accordingly, so you can simply get back to normal, while having a working dropdown.